# Repeat a Worksheet_Change on every sheet in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, events, worksheet

I got code for timestamping.

I don't want to put it on every sheet in the workbook. Tried changing the event to workbook_sheetchange, but got a compile error.

The code I want repeated on every sheet.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
xCellColumn = 12
xTimeColumn = 10
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
       Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
        For Each xRg In xDPRg
            If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: use the Workbook_SheetChange event in the ThisWorkbook module and put `sh.` in front of any `Cells` or `Range`

Comment: Also you know that worksheet_change does not fire on a change due to a calculation change, so the Else will never be the one that gets run.

Comment: Like @ScottCraner said, use  `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: Also worth noting that `Target` can be a multi-cell range, so your code needs to be able to account for that possibility.

Comment: `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` worked like a charm! perfect!